# Copying a Excel spreadsheet into a new workbook where it mirrors the original spreadsheet with formulas and formatting

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have multiple workbooks that I normally copy and paste information from the one into the other at the end of each month to do an analysis. Another woman inputs that information into the original spreadsheet. I was looking for a way to link the two workbooks so that when she inputs her information it would mirror into my workbook instead of having to copy and paste each time. The problems i am running into mainly are with the formatting because the information being entered is invoices for multiple entities with totals under them and a grand total. Every month there isn't the same amount of invoices so the amount of rows change and the total rows are never in the same spot, which messes up the formatting/shading of rows based on the invoices entity. There are tabs for each month and for each program. When I just link to the other spreadsheet it isn't formatting them while it does copy the info. Ideally I would just love for the tabs to mirror each other almost like an iframe inside my analysis workbook but I can't find anything of the sort. I have tried power queries but they do not come over formatted and looking correct. I have tried a script where everything transfers over and looks perfect but I feel like if I go that route then I am going to need more than one script for everything to work with the other spreadsheets that use the information from the ones I want to copy over. I also think that script would be pretty big because there are two tabs for each month and to write something to only copy over the month you are working on would be a lot to write as there are 48 tabs of info to compile for a year. I just want it to update dynamically and not have to run a script each time.

AM I SOL?? and am I stuck to just copying and pasting?

As I said above I have tried power queries and VBA but nothing really works for what I am looking for,

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to help you. What does the source data look like (provide example). What do you want the output to look like (provide example)? What have you tried (sample code)?

Comment: If you have multiple source worksheets all with the same type of format, then you could create some generic VBA which could copy from any one of those sheets....   First though you need to show us some actual data and/or your current code.

Comment: Welcome Dawn! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.